# consulta recursiva em tabelas relacionadas usando foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

Há um banco de dados com nome **Cadastro** e nesse banco existem três tabelas **PAIS**, **FILHOS** e **NETOS**:

[image: RELACAO TABELAS]

Na tabela **PAIS** eu tenho dois cadastro:

[image: RELCAO TABELAS]

Junto com a tabela **FILHOS**:

[image: RELACAO TABELAS]

e a tabela **NETOS**

[image: RELACAO TABELAS]

A minha *tabela* **NETOS** esta relaciona à *tabela* **FILHOS** pela *coluna* **idFILHOS** e a minha *tabela* **FILHOS** está relacionada à *tabela* **PAIS** pela *coluna* **idPAIS**.

Até agora eu acho que fiz tudo certo, esses dados iniciais são só para fins de testes, mas vamos supor que estas tabelas vão ter milhares de cadastros e eu queira fazer uma consulta pelo nome dessa pessoa, e nessa consulta trazer a relação familiar desta pessoa, independentemente da tabela que for buscar.

**Exemplo 1:**

Eu busco por *%MATILDE%*

```
MATILDE GONZAGA
E FILHA DE JOSE FIRMINO FRAGA
E NETA DE SEVERINO FIRMINO SILVA
```

**Exemplo 2:**

Eu busco por *%MARIA%*

```
MARIA LEITAO GONZAGA
E FILHA DE JOSEFINA MONICA LEITAO
E MAE DE HEITOR DOS ANJOS

# eu também teria que ter uma coluna referente ao sexo
# mas isso não vem ao caso agora
```

Resumindo: eu quero retornar o campo "nome" de todas as tabelas relacionadas resultante da minha query.

Se não ficou claro, me pergunte nos comentários.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome disso é join, veja o exemplo.

Você deve usar a função `CONCAT` para fazer a concatenação do texto fixo.

```
SELECT N.NOME AS NOME,
CONCAT(' É FILHA DE ', F.NOME) AS NOME_FILHO,
CONCAT(' E NETA DE ', P.NOME) AS NOME_PAI
FROM NETOS N
INNER JOIN FILHOS F ON F.ID = N.IDFILHOS
INNER JOIN PAIS P ON P.ID = F.IDPAI
WHERE N.NOME LIKE '%MATILDE%' /*Só um exemplo de como usar o where*/
```

Obviamente isso vai mostrar os resultados em três colunas, mas nada impede que você junte tudo numa única coluna.

Veja mais sobre os tipos de joins nessa pergunta: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/48732)

Comment: eu acho que o seu exemplo nao se emplementaria no meu codigo

Comment: Mas não tem nenhum código na pergunta...

Comment: o nome do meu DB TABELAS E COLUNAS estao todas na pergunta mals ae mas eu sou muito leigo ainda como se pode ver estou usando o phpmyadmin para me auxiliar

Comment: se eu montar uma query no php com esse codigo funciona? @jfbueno

Comment: Deve funcionar, é uma query válida. Teste no phpMyAdmin pra ver se ela está correta.

Comment: O MySQL retornou um conjunto vazio (ex. zero registros). (Consulta levou 0.0008 segundos.)

Comment: O where estava utilizando nome `MARIA` ao invés de `MATILDE`. Já atualizei a resposta, tente novamente. Aliás, você deveria ter percebido isso.

Comment: agora eu tive retorno mas nao e bem isso o que eu estou querendo exatamente eu quero recursar mesmo tabela refente a minha primare key

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41132/discussion-between-niko-bellic-and-jfbueno).

Comment: vamos supor que e nao sei em qua tabela onde eu vou encontrar MARIA dai eu quero fazer uma consulta nas 'tres' tabelas e recursar nas tabelas relacionadas recuperando a coluna nome @jfbueno

Comment: Pô, aí já é outra história, né. Sua pergunta nada tem a ver com isso, pelo menos não diretamente.