# Consulta em três tabelas por uma coluna com Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

Essa foi a forma que eu achei para fazer uma consulta nas minhas três tabelas: **PAIS**, **FILHOS** e **NETOS** usando o operador ***LIKE***:

```
SELECT `PAIS`.nome,
       `FILHOS`.nome,
       `NETOS`.nome 
 FROM  `PAIS`, `FILHOS`, `NETOS`
 WHERE `PAIS`.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%'
 OR    `FILHOS`.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%' 
 OR    `NETOS`.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%'
```

Tenho outra pergunta relacionada ao problema: [consulta recursiva em tabelas relacionadas usando foreign keys](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/134823/consulta-recursiva-em-tabelas-relacionadas-usando-foreign-keys)

Só para recapitular, estou repassando as definições de como está meu banco de dados novamente (veja a imagem abaixo):

[image]

[image]

Observe que a tabela ***FLHOS*** está relacionada com a tabela ***PAIS*** pela coluna `idPAI`, no caso `JOSE` é filho de `SEVERINO` e `MARIA` é filha de `JOSEFINA`:

[image]

> **Agora a pergunta que não quer calar:** como eu faço para trazer essa relação do `id` com o nome da pessoa através da busca pelo palavra `'%MATILDE%'` usando o operador `LIKE`?

**Exemplo:**

`MATILDE idFILHOS 1` quer dizer que é filha de `JOSE`, que é filho de `SEVERINO`, deu pra entender? Eu quero fazer essa "recursão" buscando pelo `nome`, porém trazendo somente os que estão relacionados pela chave primária `id`.

Comment: E a tabela netos? Não colocou

Comment: Isso é uma tabela muitos para muitos. Fiz um pequeno exercío agora que é capaz de ajuda-lo. Precisa de criar uma tabela pivot que vai armazenar id_pai, e id_filho só, para se puderem relacionar

Comment: @Miguel e a primeira de baixo pra cima

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque "phpmyadmin" não é um "banco de dados", leia isto pra entender as diferenças: [Qual a diferença entre o mysql e o phpmyadmin?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115692/3635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, você precisa relacionar as chaves primárias e estrangeiras das tabelas... Fazer um INNER JOIN.

OBS: Coloquei errado o JOIN. Segue código correto:

```
SELECT 
  PAIS.nome,
  FILHOS.nome, 
  NETOS.nome 
FROM PAIS 
INNER JOIN FILHOS 
  ON PAIS.id = FILHOS.idPAI 
INNER JOIN NETOS ON FILHOS.idPAI = NETOS.idFILHOS
WHERE 
  PAIS.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%' OR FILHOS.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%' OR NETOS.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%'
```

Comment: cara quase funcionou so tem um erro de sintaxe que eu nao consiguir identificar e a pK e fK ja esta configurada **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.idFILHHOS WHERE PAIS.nome LIKE '%MATILDE%' OR FILHOS.nome LIKE '%MATILDE% OR NETOS.nome LIKE '%MATILDE% at line 1**' nao sei se eu estou equivocado mas parece que o INNER JOIN nao funciona em conjunto com o WHERE

Comment: @NikoBellic Altere o último INNER JOIN > INNER NETOS JOIN FILHOS.id = NETOS.idFilhos. Elle esqueceu de colocar o nome da tabela no último INNER JOIN.

Comment: ah caramba agora funcionou melhor ainda agora eu sei como o INNER JOIN funciona caras valeu mesmo qualquer coisa que eu poder ajudar tambem tamo ai